# Suggestions for resources about statistical analysis

Tags: anova, variance, standard-deviation, standard-error, error

I am wondering if anyone has suggestions for resources discussing how to properly carry out statistical analysis across multiple groups, for something like evaluating the accuracy of a thermometer that has the following:

a) variation between the readings from a single device.

b) variation between units of the same manufacturing batch.

c) variation between different manufacturing batches

I am mostly unsure of how you would (or even should?) express the compounding effect these errors would have. Would ANOVA be appropriate? Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Anova could be appropriate, maybe better variance components. Search this site, also for quality control